# Working with Twitter OAuth... need some help

Tags: php, html, twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm working through an unofficial example of Twitter's OAuth by Pete Warden, [here](https://github.com/petewarden/twitteroauthexample).

I need help with a few things... I'm trying to get it to work through localhost but I can't get the Callback URL which I have set to `http://bit.ly/localhost/twitter/index.php/` when I log in to bring me back to the original page `index.php`, located in `localhost/twitter/index.php` where the login link is to begin with. Instead it brings me back to the base base of my localhost.

Additionally, I get an error `Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in C:\wamp\www\twitter\index.php on line 295`

I can't see how a session has already been started... this is literally the ONLY place in all of the files in his entire his example where `session_start()` is called.

Let me know if you can figure out why these things are happening.

Comment: it it not an error, a notice.

Comment: Could you please include a piece of the source code where callback URL is set to the OAuth request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have [`session.auto_start = 1`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.auto-start) in your php.ini.
You can check whether it is enabled by calling `phpinfo()`.

Comment: Good call, I do have that enabled. Thank you for that... Still having trouble figuring out the rest of the example though.